# Como saber se um número é inteiro

Tags: algoritmo, inteiros, visualg

Preciso desenvolver um algoritmo aonde, ele divide um número por 2, até chegar no resto da divisão, e preciso saber se o resto desta divisão é um número inteiro, qual método posso aplicar para desenvolver este problema?

onde:

```
funcao menu_8():inteiro
var
inicio
para contador de 0 ate 12 faca
     se (i[contador] % 2 = 1) entao
        escreva (" Potencia de 2: ", i[contador])
     fimse
fimpara
escreval(" ")
fimfuncao
```

Este algoritmo será aplicado, no seguinte, se o usuário digitar no vetor, um numero que seja potencia de 2, deverá exibir em tela este valor.

Onde vou usar, Log de base 10, para dividir o número digitado por 2 log de 10, e se o resultado da divisão de um numero inteiro, ai quer dizer que é base de dois, o número digitado pelo usuário, caso contrario não é.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resto da divisão é um número inteiro, por definição. Se não for inteiro, não é resto. Alias toda a descrição do problema não parece fazer o menos sentido.  Vou responder o título da pergunta.

Basicamente é isto:

```
x == int(x)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Int.ptg).

A segunda expressão converte o número para um inteiro. Se ele continuar igual, significa que ele é inteiro, se for diferente é porque o número tinha uma parte decimal.

Comment: Isso funciona no Visualg em portugol??

Comment: @Mauricio Provavelmente precisa de alguma adaptação.